# Вывести дублирующиеся значения друг на против друга

Tags: sql, sql-server

Например, в таблице есть какие-то дубли по нескольким поля и нужно их вывести друг на против друга.

Но вот не задача, значения будут задублированы.

Т.е сначала выведется Правый дубль|Левый дубль, а где-то внизу все наоборот.

Я делаю это таким образом:

```
DECLARE @TMP TABLE  (ID INT,Val NVARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO @TMP VALUES 
(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'B')



SELECT * FROM @TMP t1
JOIN @TMP t2 ON t2.ID <>t1.ID
WHERE t2.Val=t1.Val
```

Какие существую способы избавления от этого побочного эффекта? Или единственный выход-это в курсоре-это подчистить?

Comment: Заменить "<>" на ">".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо сравнения на неравенство по ID можно сравнивать на больше\меньше.
Например:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  @TMP t1
JOIN  @TMP t2 
ON    t2.ID > t1.ID
WHERE t2.Val = t1.Val
```

Comment: Мда, решение оказалось столь простым...